# <component> in vue always rendering newline

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Everytime I insert  tag in my main app it always rendering a new line, couldn't it be inline? I want to achieve something like this :

```
<p>This is a component :<component></component></p>
<!--worked with other html tags-->
```

Result instead :

```
This is a component :
component content
```

Of course I can insert prefix `This is a component :` as props in the component so it can be inline, at least for displaying, but that's not always I intended to be..

I wonder also where Vue store css template for component.
Thanks community.

Comment: What do you mean "where Vue store css template"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your component isn't rendering on a new line. It is rendering based on the rendering rules for HTML. If your component's root tag is a block element, then it will be rendered on the next line. If it is an inline element, then it will be rendered inline.

```js
console.clear()

const Inline = {
  template: `<span>This is inline</span>`
}

const Newline = {
  template: `<div>This is on a new line</div>`
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Inline,
    Newline
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>This is an inline component:
    <component is="Inline"></component>
  </p>
  <p>This is a block component:
    <component is="Newline"></component>
  </p>
</div>
```

In the above example, the `Inline` component's root tag is a `span`. Spans are inline elements. The `Newline` component's root tag is a `div`. Divs are block level elements and the text is on the next line.

You could also use `display: inline` on a `div` and cause the component to be rendered inline.

```js
console.clear()

const Newline = {
  template: `<div style="display: inline">This is on the same line</div>`
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    Newline,
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p>This is a block component that displays inline:
    <component is="Newline"></component>
  </p>
</div>
```

The HTML rendered by Vue follows all the layout rules of HTML you hand write. There's no magic involved.

Comment: Thanks, in my case it's further complicated with I'm using it inside electron app and nested/messy css scoped.. pheww.. Should've jsfiddle'd it first before assumed.